# Condicionales en un evento JavaScript

Tags: javascript, condiciones, dom, eventos

que tal? Estoy haciendo un juego de preguntas con el DOM y me encuentro trabada en una cosa:
Quiero que, cuando tocas uno de los tres botones, al seleccionado, se le aplique una clase, y a los otros dos, otra, para que desaparezcan.
Pero no se manejar los condicionales con el evento. Este codigo tiene recursividad, y está muy mal, pero es que no sabia como resolverlo.
El error que se presenta al ejecutarlo acá es el mismo que si lo corro en mi navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Dejo aquí el link para probarlo en vivo: https://victoriaileanarodriguezmora.github.io/Marvell/

```js
let botonJugas = document.querySelector(".jugas")
let titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo")
let secccionQuizz = document.querySelector(".quizz")
let divCategorias = document.querySelector(".categorias")
let contenedorPreguntas = document.querySelector(".contenedor__preguntas")
let botonesCategorias = document.querySelectorAll(".categorias > button")
let botonUCM = document.querySelector(".botonUCM")
let botonXMEN = document.querySelector(".botonXMEN")
let botonTODO = document.querySelector(".botonTODO")

contenedorPreguntas.classList.add("fadeOut")
divCategorias.classList.add("fadeOut")


// Se cliake el boton ¿JUGAS?
botonJugas.addEventListener("click", fadeOutInicial)
    //Se oculta ese boton, y la presentacion del Inicio
function fadeOutInicial() {
    botonJugas.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
    titulo.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
        // Se muestran las categorias para jugar
    divCategorias.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
}

//Se muestran los 3 botones para elegir


function showCategories() {

    for (let i = 0; i < botonesCategorias.length; i++) {
        if (botonesCategorias[i].addEventListener("click", showCategories)) {
            this.classList.toggle("categorias__boton")
            this.classList.add("buttonSelected")
            contenedorPreguntas.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
        } else {
            this.classList.toggle("fadeOut")

        }

    }
}
showCategories()
```

```css
.fadeOut {
    transition: 100ms;
    display: none;
}

.displayNone {
    display: none;
}

.fadeShow {
    transition: 300ms;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.buttonSelected {
    transition: 500ms;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border: 5px solid rgb(38, 0, 255);
    width: 6%;
    border-radius: 44px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #060052;
    color: white;
    left: 1%;
    top: 20%;
    &:hover {
        border-color: #060052;
        background-color: rgb(38, 0, 255);
    }
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
        <!-- titulo -->
        <section id="titulo">
            <h1 class="section__titulo">MARVEL QUIZZ</h1>
            <p class="section__parrafo">
                Luego de haber visto la guia (y las peliculas) , vas a ser tod@ un@ expert@ sobre Marvel. Y en este quizz vas a poder demostrarlo! <span class="section__span">El quizz es solo sobre Marvel Studios. Osea,
                    sólo las peliculas.</span>
            </p>
        </section>
        <!-- titulo -->
        <section class="quizz">

            <button class="jugas">
                ¿JUGAS?
            </button>

            <div class="categorias">
                <button class="categorias__boton botonUCM">MCU</button>
                <button class="categorias__boton botonXMEN">X-Men</button>
                <button class="categorias__boton botonTODO">TODO</button>
            </div>

            <div class="contenedor__preguntas">
                <div class="div__pregunta">
                    <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma?</h2>
                    <img src="">
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Viuda Negra </button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Bruja Escarlata</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Gamora</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Carol Danvers</button>

                </div>
                <div class="div__pregunta">
                    <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">¿Qué personajes tiene un premio por intrepretar en live action más veces a un superhéroe de marvel?</h2>
                    <img src="">
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Hugh JackMan & Patrick Stewart</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Hugh Jackman & Robert D. Junior</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Patrick Stewart & Robert D. Junior</button>
                </div>
                <div class="div__pregunta">
                    <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">Que raza es aliada de Loki en Avengers?</h2>
                    <img src="">
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Chitauri</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Klyntar</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Kronans</button>
                    <button class="pregunta__opcion">Centaurians</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

    </main>
```

---

https://victoriaileanarodriguezmora.github.io/Marvell/html/quizz.html este es link directo al quizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal Victoria? te dejo por aca un par de recomendaciones y la solucion. Desde ya, muy buena estetica tiene la pagina

1 - nunca te esta entrando en el condicional if, siempre en el else de showCategories()

2 - showCategories() tiene un nombre que referencia a mostrar categorias, las cuales ya se muestran con la salida de fadeOutInicial. Por ende no hace falta esta funcion.

3 - Siempre que diferencies a un elemento unico es mejor que sea por id (mas adelante al interactuar con bases de datos, detectaras la importancia de id).

4 - si no entiendes el switch case, lo veras cuando aprendas condicionales (en vez de hacer varios if preguntando cada caso, se aplica dicha funcion)

5 - se le agrega el onclick en html si estas haciendo este tipo de paginas (luego cuando uses librerias o frameworks te ahorraras muchas de estas cuestiones)

HTML

```js
let botonJugas = document.querySelector(".jugas")
let titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo")
let secccionQuizz = document.querySelector(".quizz")
let divCategorias = document.querySelector(".categorias")
let contenedorPreguntas = document.querySelector(".contenedor__preguntas")
let botonesCategorias = document.querySelectorAll(".categorias > button")
let botonUCM = document.querySelector("#botonUCM")
let botonXMEN = document.querySelector("#botonXMEN")
let botonTODO = document.querySelector("#botonTODO")

contenedorPreguntas.classList.add("fadeOut")
divCategorias.classList.add("fadeOut")


// Se cliake el boton ¿JUGAS?
botonJugas.addEventListener("click", fadeOutInicial)
    //Se oculta ese boton, y la presentacion del Inicio
function fadeOutInicial() {
    botonJugas.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
    titulo.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
        // Se muestran las categorias para jugar
    divCategorias.classList.toggle("fadeOut")
}

function categorySelected(x){
    console.log(botonUCM.classList)
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            botonXMEN.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            botonTODO.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            break;
    
        case 2:
            botonUCM.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            botonTODO.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            break;
    
        case 3:
            botonUCM.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            botonXMEN.classList.toggle('fadeOut');
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

```css
.fadeOut {
    transition: 100ms;
    display: none;
}

.displayNone {
    display: none;
}

.fadeShow {
    transition: 300ms;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.buttonSelected{
    transition: 500ms;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border: 5px solid rgb(38, 0, 255);
    width: 6%;
    border-radius: 44px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #060052;
    color: white;
    left: 1%;
    top: 20%;    
}

.buttonSelected:hover {
    border-color: #060052;
    background-color: rgb(38, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>problem1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />    
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="main">
      <!-- titulo -->
      <section id="titulo">
        <h1 class="section__titulo">MARVEL QUIZZ</h1>
        <p class="section__parrafo">
          Luego de haber visto la guia (y las peliculas) , vas a ser tod@ un@
          expert@ sobre Marvel. Y en este quizz vas a poder demostrarlo!
          <span class="section__span"
            >El quizz es solo sobre Marvel Studios. Osea, sólo las
            peliculas.</span
          >
        </p>
      </section>
      <!-- titulo -->
      <section class="quizz">
        <button class="jugas">¿JUGAS?</button>

        <div class="categorias">
          <button class="categorias__boton" id="botonUCM" onclick="categorySelected(1)">MCU</button>
          <button class="categorias__boton" id="botonXMEN" onclick="categorySelected(2)">X-Men</button>
          <button class="categorias__boton" id="botonTODO" onclick="categorySelected(3)">TODO</button>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor__preguntas">
          <div class="div__pregunta">
            <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">
              ¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma?
            </h2>
            <img src="" />
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Viuda Negra</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Bruja Escarlata</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Gamora</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Carol Danvers</button>
          </div>
          <div class="div__pregunta">
            <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">
              ¿Qué personajes tiene un premio por intrepretar en live action más
              veces a un superhéroe de marvel?
            </h2>
            <img src="" />
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">
              Hugh JackMan & Patrick Stewart
            </button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">
              Hugh Jackman & Robert D. Junior
            </button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">
              Patrick Stewart & Robert D. Junior
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="div__pregunta">
            <h2 class="pregunta__titulo">
              Que raza es aliada de Loki en Avengers?
            </h2>
            <img src="" />
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Chitauri</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Klyntar</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Kronans</button>
            <button class="pregunta__opcion">Centaurians</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta Samuel!!!

Comment: Si manejo switch! Pero no se me habia ocurrido. Crack

Comment: Como podria tener todo en Js? Intenté esto pero no funcionó 
for (let i = 0; i < arrBotones.length; i++) {
    arrBotones[i].addEventListener("click", categorySelected(arrBotones[i]))    
}